ESTA Application stuck in "Authorization Pending". What next steps can I take?
I’m an Australian citizen (formerly an Indian citizen) and I applied for an ESTA about three days ago. My application status is still showing as “Authorization Pending”. Normally applications are being approved in about 30mins to 4 hrs timeframe.  I’m looking for advice from anyone who has recently been in a similar situation, as I’m quite stressed about this with my travel date coming up in about four weeks.
Regarding the ESTA eligibility question about visa refusals, I answered “YES” and provided the following details:
When: 2003
Where: Chennai, India
Reason: F1 Visa rejection due to insufficient GRE & TOEFL scores
I had one student visa refusal back in 2003 for the reason mentioned above.
Will this have any impact on my ESTA approval?
My ESTA status has been “Authorization Pending” for three working days now. Has anyone experienced something similar recently? Any advice, thoughts, or suggestions on what to do next would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

While most ESTA applications are processed rather quickly, the official guideline is "usually within 72 hours", so you should probably wait a couple more days. Did you correctly give details about your other/previous citizenship? Did you actually lose your Indian citizenship?

They'll normally be processed automatically very quickly if you say "no" to all the questions, but your answer probably means it has to go to a human being to look at. If you can, give it a few more days.

@jcaron Yeah, have given all the details correctly. Yeah, lost my Indian Citizenship and got my Australian passport.

thanks @StuartF Just curious to know how long it takes.. Anyways, will wait and watch. Thanks!

Lost (how?) or renounced Indian citizenship?

@JonCuster Indians lose citizenship automatically if they naturalize elsewhere.

Oops.. yeah, I mean renounced my Indian Citizenship.. sorry..

Just to update the progress, finally got my ESTA approved after about 5 days. Thanks all for your inputs! Appreciate it.
